# compact inverse is compact in canonical homomorphism

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-groups, continuous-homomorphisms

Let $G$ be locally compact Hausdorff group. Let $N$ be a closed normal subgroup of $G$. Let $f:G\to G/N$ be the canonical homomorphism. I want to show that for every compact subset $C$ of $G/N$, there exists a compact $S\subset G$, such that $f(S)=C$.
Thanks for all the help

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thank you, I will read it carefully :)

Comment: @AlexRavsky the answer you posted is not the same. Note that in my case **N** is not compact, but only closed. So I cannot use the theorems you stated.

Comment: Oops, indeed. I was inattentive. I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positive answer to your question is a corollary of Theorem 4.6.22 from “Topological groups and related structures” by Alexander V. Arhangel'skii and Mikhail G. Tkachenko.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The statement here is even stronger. Much appreciated